# Nilpotent iff every maximal subgroup is normal

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let the commutator of $x$ and $y$ is:

$$[x,y]= x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$$

$$[G, G] = \langle \{[x, y]\ \mid x,y\in G\}\rangle$$

$[G , G]$ is called the commutator subgroup of group $G$.

Now let us see the *lower central series* of group $G$.

$$G = L^{0}(G) \ge L^{1}(G) \cdots  $$

Where $L^{i+1}(G) = [G,L^{i}(G)]$.

If the lower central series for $G$ terminates in $\{1\}$ then we say group is **nilpotent**.

**Claim :** A finite group $G$ is nilpotent iff if every maximal subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$

Proof : Let me prove first that if every maximal subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$ then group $G$ is nilpotent

Let $H$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$, by hypothesis it is normal so we get

$\{1\}\le H \le G$

As $H$ is maximal subgroup of $G$ it is not possible that we have some $H_1$ in which is non-trivial and a subgroup of $H$.

**Is there anything more which I need to prove in this direction**?

Other direction 
If finite group $G$ is nilpotent then every subgroup of $G$ is maximal.

If $G$ is nilpotent then by above definition it admits an lower central series ..

**I need a hint how to prove this direction**

Comment: Downvoter care to explain

Answer (score 6):

To be fair I don't see how $G \ge H \ge \{1\}$ helps you prove that $G$ is nilpotent.

First of all assume that $G$ isn't the trivial group, nor a $p$-group, as it's trivial that claim holds for those groups.

Anyway, here's a way how to prove the fact above. Assume that each maximal subgroup of $G$ is normal. Now let $P$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. Obviously $P \not = G$. Now we know that if each Sylow subgroup is normal in $G$, then it's nilpotent. So assume that $N[P] \not = G$. Then we have that $N[P] \le M < G$, where $M$ is some maximal subgroup of $G$. Now by [Frattini's Argument](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Frattini's_argument) we have:

$$G = MN_G[P] = M$$

which is a contradiction and hence $N[P] = G$ and so $P \lhd G$ and so $G$ is nilpotent.

For the other way first prove that [nilpotent subgroups satisfy the nilpotent condition](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Nilpotent_implies_normalizer_condition). Then let $M$ be any maximal subgroup of $G$, then we have that $M < N[M]$, but from the maximality of $M$ we must have $N[M] = G$ and hence $M \lhd G$ and hence the proof.

Comment: Groups of order $p$ do have a maximal subgroup, the trivial subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, yeah! I guess too often I overlook the whole group and the trivial subgroup. Anyway that case needs to be considered separately, as then in the case first part $G=P$.

Comment: @Stefan4024 I thought to prove $G$ is nilpotent I have to just come with an   lower central series that's why I come up with $G \ge H \ge {1}$.

Comment: @old Yeah, the idea is right, but how do you prove that it's indeed a lower series?

Comment: @ Stefan4024 I have taken $H$ as a maximal subgroup so it is normal in $G$ and second thing is $\{1\}$ Is subgroup of $H$ and $\{1\}$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: @old You have written the definition of a lower central series in the question. Now check whether $G \ge \ H \ge \{1\}$ is such a series. In particular is the following true $H = \langle [G:G] \rangle$